# create multiple dependent dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  How to i create a multiple dependent dropdown?
```

for eg:-

```
<select id="one">
<option value="a">animal</option>
<option value="b">bird</option>
</select>
<select id="two_a">
<option value="a1">lion</option>
<option value="a2">tiger</option>
 </select>
<select id="two_b">
<option value="b1">sparrow</option>
<option value="b2">eagle</option>
</select>
```

the dropdown "two_a" should appear if i choose "animal" in the first dropdown and the dropdown "two_b" should appear if i choose "bird"

Comment: You can use javascript to check which value is selected and based on the selected value, you can show/hide other dropdown. Also, when you ask something, please add link to jsfiddle or at least post what you have tried.

Comment: There's a ton of examples at SO, and a lot more can be found from internet. Just do some search.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make use of the [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and write a simple event on the `one` select list. Then you can use the `value` of the selected item to show the appropriate child list.

Here's a running demonstration:

```js
$('#one').change(function() {
  $('select[id^="two_"]').hide();
  $('#two_' + this.value).show();
});
```

```css
select[id^="two_"] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
  <option value="a">animal</option>
  <option value="b">bird</option>
</select>
<select id="two_a">
  <option value="a1">lion</option>
  <option value="a2">tiger</option>
</select>
<select id="two_b">
  <option value="b1">sparrow</option>
  <option value="b2">eagle</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `two_a` and `two_b` dropdowns to have `display: none` and use jQuery to detect for changes in dropdown `one` and use `.hide()` and `.show()` on the appropriate dropdowns to show/hide them. 
See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpPLpp for a demonstration.