# Dynamic dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I dont know jquery at all. But I have to design a dynamic dropdown with cities and towns depending on cities. I'm using Ruby on Rails by the way.
Here is my view code:

```
  <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Şehir:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.limit(2), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
          </div>
      </div>
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" id="ilce_id">İlçe:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <%= f.grouped_collection_select :town_id, City.order(:name), :towns, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
          </br>
          </br>
          </div>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
```

And jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {
  var towns;
  $('#ilce_id').hide();
  $('#location_town_id').parent().hide();
  towns = $('#location_town_id').html();
  return $('#location_city_id').change(function() {
    var city, escaped_city, options;
    city = $('#location_city_id :selected').text();
    escaped_city = city.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    options = $(towns).filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_city + "']").html();
    if (options) {
      $('#ilce_id').show();
      $('#location_town_id').html(options);
      return $('#location_town_id').parent().show();
    } else {
      $('#location_town_id').empty();
      $('#location_town_id').parent().hide();
      return $('#ilce_id').hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

This code is working good if I'm using this in the "new" page. But in "edit" view, even if city and town is already selected, town selection does not appear. I want it to be like:

- If city and town are already selected and the controller renders "edit" page, town selection should appear and already selected town should be active option. (I mean already selected town should be selected option on the dropdown.)
- If only city is already selected and the controller renders "edit" page, town selection should appear and "prompt" should be active ( like "Select a town...) on the dropdown.

Maybe it's not a big deal but since I dont know js and jquery, I could not manage it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's something similar to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082390/361762

Comment: Your example code is lacking the resulting HTML that the JavaScript would interact with. It makes it very hard to help or understand your script's function.